# Difference between Foreach and For Loops?

Tags: c++, for-loop, foreach

What's the real difference between a foreach and for loop if either can get the same job done? I'm learning C++ and apparently there is no foreach loop for its arrays :(

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/for_each/ - use STL containers instead of arrays and you *do* have it.

Comment: @BrianRoach Actually, you don't even have to use an STL container in the latest standard.  You can use `std::begin()` and `std::end()` in the `std::for_each` function.

Comment: Qt (a popular cross-platform C++ toolkit) provides [a `foreach` construct](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qtglobal.html#foreach).

Comment: @MichaelPrice - Yeah ... I'm kinda mixed on whether to start answering C++ questions with C++11 answers. Same thing with Java 7. I suppose offering it as an additional alternative is responsible.

Comment: @BrianRoach While this is more *meta*, I'd prefer deprecating the C++11 tag in favor of adding a C++ 98/03 tag that is reserved for questions specific to that version.  The same goes for answers.  If only those darn compilers would implement the full standard.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no "foreach" language construct in C++, a least not literally. C++11 introduces something that's "as good as" a foreach loop, though.

The traditional `for` loop has something to do with evaluating conditions and performing repeated operations. It's a very general control structure. Its most popular use is to iterate over container or array contents, but that's just a tiny fraction of what you can do with it.

A "foreach" loop, on the other hand, is explicitly designed to iterate over container elements.

Example:

```
int arr[5] = { 1, 3, 5, 2, 4 };

for (int & n : arr) { n *= 2; } // "for-each" loop, new in C++11

for (size_t i = 0; i != 5; ++i) { arr[i] *= 2; } // "classic" for loop
```

In the second for, we use a traditional `for` loop to increment an auxiliary variable `i` in order to access the container `arr`. The first, *range-based* loop does not expose any details of the iteration, but just says "do this and that to each element in the collection".

Since the traditional `for` loop is a very general control structure, it can also be used in unusual ways:

```
std::vector<std::string> all_lines;
for (std::string line; std::cin >> line; all_lines.push_back(line))
{
  std::cout << "On line " << (all_lines.size() + 1) << " you said: " << line << std::endl;
}
```

You can trivially rewrite `for(A; B; C)` as a while loop:

```
{  // scope!
  A;
  while (true && B)
  {
    {  // more scope!
      /* for loop body */
    }
    C;
  }
}
```

**Edit:** I would probably be remiss not to mention the *library function template* `std::for_each` from `<algorithm>`, which in conjunction with lambdas is a very nice and self-descriptive way to iterate over arbitrary *ranges* (not just entire *containers*). It has existed since Day 1, but before lambdas it was a show-stopping pain to use.

---

**Update:** I thought of something else that might be relevant here: A "foreach" loop generally assumes that you *don't modify* the container. A common type of looping that modifies the container requires the traditional `for`-loop; as for example in this typical  `erase` pattern:

```
for(Container::const_iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end() /* not hoisted! */; /* no increment */ )
{
  // do something
  if (suitable_condition)
  {
    v.erase(it++);   // or it = v.erase(it), depending on container type
  }
  else
  {
    ++it;
  }
}
```

Comment: So really I can use them interchangeably but can possibly do more with a `for` loop?

Comment: @Howdy_McGee: Yes. I added an unusual `for` example. The standard `for` loop really is just short for, "a) initialize some stuff; b) if some condition holds, do some stuff; c) perform some operation; d) goto b)".

Comment: @Howdy_McGee: It might help you to think of a `for` loop as a convenient `while` loop. I added that explanation.

Comment: Thanks, I understand the for loop but why do other languages need a foreach if a for can do the same thing and then some ya know

Comment: @Howdy_McGee: It's all about expression of intent. If you have a container, the for-each (or ranged-for, in C++) loop lets you express that you want to access container elements, nothing more and nothing less. Note how the range-based loop has a much simpler body, since no unnecessary information is exposed. Programming is all about expressing a mental model, and having an idiomatic construction available helps to make your code clearer and more self-explanatory.

Comment: My answer to this 'why' question is for syntatic sugar....it's less typing for mostly the same behavior.  If you have access to the collection's objects, you don't (usually) need access to the index of where that object is.

Comment: Or, in one sentence, "Nobody wants to read someone else's `for` loop." With range-based loops, this may just have become a little less painful.

Comment: @dlgrasse: Sort of. It's more idiomatic, and it's just The Right Thing in terms of doing what you *mean*, and not making you write something that only very indirectly and verbosely and noisily contains what you want.

Comment: @KerrekSB: I'll agree that that could be a reason why the different constructs are in the language, but from a developer's perspective i don't go around thinking "which one do i use based on the intent i want to express".  and besides, using a less noisy and verbose syntax is what sytactic sugar is.

Comment: @dlgrasse: I'm afraid that might say more about you than it does about C++ :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB: fair enough.  i have no qualms acknowleding that, IMO, perfection is when there's nothing left to remove :-)  i use the foreach as often as i can.

Answer (score 1):

`foreach` generally has 1 parameter, `for` has 3. Anything `foreach` can do `for` can too. Part of the reason why `foreach` doesn't exist in C++ is because the number of iterations can't always be inferred from the type.

I believe boost library has a method of getting `foreach` to work, and C++11 has a range-based of `for`:

```
int my_array[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
for (int &x : my_array) {
    x *= 2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is something like for each for arrays in C++ and that is [iterators](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/). Both loops are essentially identical with the only difference being - with an ordinary for loop you have an index which you might need depending on what type of data you are accessing and whether you need to do some calculations with the index and there is (probably) an increased chance of off-by-one errors. Whereas foreach loops just guarantee that will be executed as many times as there are elements in the array without exposing an index (which you can mimic) so as a I said they are essentially the same but their usage largely depends on the way you manipulate your data.

Answer (score 0):

"For Each" syntax is used to iterate through a collection of objects, while a for loop is a loop that will execute for a given range.  C++ does have for_each in its STL and can be used to iterate through linear object containers such as a vector.

Comment: A `for` loop has nothing to do with "ranges". It's about checking conditionals and executing statements.

Comment: Technically you are correct, but when compared to for_each range is appropriate.  I'd even stake the claim that most for loop conditions written are based on some type of range, and generally iterate through some type of indexed data.  Using a for loop to test boolean "conditionals" is inappropriate when you have do and while loops available.

Answer (score 0):

In other languages with a foreach construct, they're usually convenience for not having to index into the collection you're looping over.  That is, you're given the next object in the collection without having access to (or need for) the index itself.  If you need the index for some reason, you'll usually need the for loop, though in some languages you have access to the counter in their 'foreach'.

Answer (score 0):

as  experience test , FOR is more Faster  than FOREACH